# Antlr4 - Parse string during edition

Tags: c++, antlr4

An Antlr4 grammar I have created turns boolean expressions into object trees, with a listener.
For instance `And({a} = 'a', {c} = 'c')` is transformed into a tree with:

- For the root, a class instance containing the `AND`
- Under it, the 2 leaves for `{a} = 'a'` (meaning field `{a}` equals value `'a'`) and `{c} = 'c'`

I would like to support "real-time" parsing of a text being edited from a GUI. Very frequently, text in the middle of being edited cannot be parsed entirely successfully (only portions of it will). When that happens, instead of returning nothing (=current behavior), I would like to still return a tree; a flag is to be set to true for nodes that cannot be parsed.

Minimal grammar (to be compiled, in my case, with options `-Dlanguage=Cpp -no-visitor -listener`):

```
grammar Condition;          
@header
{
#include "QSCondition.h"
#undef emit
}
expr                   returns [QSCondition* condition]
                       :    prefixedExpr  EOF
                       ;

prefixedExpr           returns [QSCondition* condition]
                       :    boolOp=AND '(' prefixedExprList ')' 
                       |    boolOp=OR  '(' prefixedExprList ')'
                       |    atomicExpr
                       ;

prefixedExprList       :    prefixedExprList ',' prefixedExpr
                       |    prefixedExpr
                       ;

atomicExpr             returns [QSCondition* condition]
                       :    '{' leftProp=property '}' op=OPERATOR  '{' rightProp=property '}'
                       |    '{' leftProp=property '}' op=OPERATOR      rightVal=STRING
                       ;

property               returns [std::vector<std::string> propList]
                       :    property'.'FIELD { $propList.push_back($FIELD.text); }
                       |    FIELD            { $propList.push_back($FIELD.text); }
                       ;


WS            : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip;
AND           : [Aa][Nn][Dd];
OR            : [Oo][Rr];
OPERATOR      : ('='|'<'|'>'|'<='|'>='|'<>');
FIELD         : [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*;
STRING        : '\'' .*? '\'';
```

For a lack of a better idea, I am looking to change the below method of my listener to catch the exception. This is a proof of concept to see what I could catch:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <debugapi.h>
void aQSConditionExpressionListener::exitAtomicExpr(ConditionParser::AtomicExprContext* ctx)
{
    if (ctx->exception) {
        OutputDebugStringA("Exception: ");
        OutputDebugStringA(ctx->getText().c_str());
        OutputDebugStringA("\n");
    }
    else {
        OutputDebugStringA("OK: ");
        OutputDebugStringA(ctx->getText().c_str());
        OutputDebugStringA("\n");
    }
}
```

Some test results:

1. In the middle of changing `And({a} = 'a', {c} = 'c')` to `And({a} = 'a', {c} = 'c', {d} = 'd')`:
   When on `And({a} = 'a', {c} = 'c', {d)` (appending a condition):

   - `OK: {a}='a'` (as expected)
   - `OK: {c}='c'` (as expected)
   - `Exception: {d` (as expected)
2. In the middle of changing `And({a} = 'a', {c} = 'c', {d} = 'd')` to `And({a} = 'a', {b} = 'b', {c} = 'c', {d} = 'd')`:
   When on `And({a} = 'a', {b} {c} = 'c', {d} = 'd')` (typing text in the middle):

   - `OK: {a}='a'` (as expected)
   - `Exception: {b}{c}='c'` (as expected)
   - OK: {d}='d' (unsure if I should have expected Antlr to manage to resume the parsing).

   But then on `And({a} = 'a', {b} = {c} = 'c')` (after adding `=`) I get OK where I would have like to have an exception:

   - `OK: {a}='a'` (as expected)
   - `OK: {b}={c}` (as expected? not what I want anyway: here, Antlr gives up parsing in the middle of the string)

I feel like I am not on the right track.
What is the right (generic) way to support string in the middle of being edited?